# CakePHP AjaxHandler->respond() returning Error 500

Tags: php, ajax, apache, cakephp

I'm faced with a very annoying issue and I can't figure it out...

I'm currently using PHP 5.6 with CakePHP 2.3 on a pretty big project with three separate repositories (each one using a different CakePHP installation). I'm on an Apache local server, on Ubuntu.

The websites are working fine, I can create data, update and delete, except when I use Ajax with POST HTTP method. When I do so, **the request is executed** (data is edited/created/deleted) but the function `$this->AjaxHandler->respond('json');` returns nothing, which cause an HTTP error 500 for my ajax, waiting a response.

There is no error message in my Apache logs nor CakePHP logs.

#### My controller

```
<?php

public function edit($id = null) {

    $this->ClientPayment->id = $id;
    $this->ClientPayment->save($this->request->data)

    if ($this->request->is('ajax')){
        $this->AjaxHandler->response(true, $this->ClientPayment->read(),__('The client payment has been saved'));
        // At this point, everything went fine, clientPayment was saved
        // and $this->ClientPayment contain everything we need

        $this->AjaxHandler->respond('json');
    }
```

#### My ajax script

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#ClientPaymentEditForm").submit(function( event ) {
            ajaxSubmitForm($(this), function(data){
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm really confused, because this code is used on a staging/prod server, and it work fine, as if my Apache installation or my PHP installation was wrong (plugin missing, cross-domain request, ...) but I searched for all of the known issues, and nothing seem to work.

I can gather all sort of info if someone have some track or ideas to debug it!

Thanks in advance, I'm really struggling on it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

first I tested first with Postman, I can show you this is the way i do it, before the frontend I recomend that uses Postman, after send data of ajax.

```
   public function edit()
    {
      $data = ['result' => 'fail', 'id' => 'null'];
      $errors = $this->ClientPayment->validator()->errors($this->request->getData());
      if(empty($errors))
      {
          $clientPayment = $this->ClientPayment->newEntity($this->request->getData());

          //You can get the data sent with your variables and assign them to their correct variables

          $clientPayment->id = $this->request->getData('id');
          $clientPayment->name = $this->request->getData('name');

          if ($this->ClientPayment->save($clientPayment))
          {
              $this->set([
                    'success' => true,
                    'data' => $clientPayment,
                    '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
                ]);
          }
      } else {

          $data['error'] = $errors;
      }
      $this->set(compact('data'));
      $this->set('_serialize', ['data']);


    }
```

Comment: I don't understand much of your answer, but trying the request with Postman is a good idea, I'm working on it and i'll tell you what's up.